# Redirect but keep the ENTIRE URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got a problem with my domain structure (the title describes it very well).

**What I've tested so far**:
I googled a lot and found many threads about "Redirect from domainA to domainB without changing the URL" (often with .htaccess). They talk about simple redirect rules and the proxy flag and so on. So I tried a lot of them but everytime they just keep the path after domainB and redirect then to domainA.

**What I want (detailed)**: I've got two domains with different IPs and when someone hit "http://www.domainA.com" it should just SHOW the content from "http://www.domainB.com" but also SHOW the URL from domainA. So when one is browsing trough my website like "http://www.domainA.com/link1" it also should show the content from "http://www.domainB.com/link1", but show the URL with "domainA".

Of course I could show you some htaccess code I used, but I start to think that htaccess is not the solution.

So I ask you guys: Is this possible with htaccess? What other solutions are possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Mod_proxy module.

Put below in your virtualhost for www.domainA.com

```
ProxyPass        / http://www.domainB.com
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.domainB.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved with help of Mod_proxy_ajp & Mod_JK module.

Comment: That's correct, solution which I provided is basedon Mod_proxy however not on Mod_proxy_ajp & Mod_jk module